# Rendering Hybrid Access Token vs Implicit Flow

Tags: oauth, asp.net-identity, openid-connect, identityserver3

Hey guys what do you think,

is rendering an Access Token that I got via Hybrid Flow in code-behind to my Java Script as "non-secure" as using Implicit Flow in Open ID Connect?

Answer (score 1):

If you need the token on the client in your JS code - you somehow need to transmit it.

The APIs you are planning to call have to be considered public at this point.